# How solve $[20]_3^{-1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

What does this mean, $[20]_3^{-1}$? it's from the topic rings, fields and residue classes.

Can you give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: Where are you getting it from? The first time you encounter this notation should not be in a problem or homework exercise, it should be in some sort of notes that would explain in detail what it means.

Comment: You are right and I have done similar examples in algebra class, but this notation is new to me.

Comment: In addition to Ashot's answer, I'll give a hint: $\gcd(20, 3) = 1$, so think Euclidean algorithm and Bezout's identity.  (Even though brute force also gets you there quickly, it's not always so easy that way.)

Comment: Thanks, the equivalence of  $x\times20\equiv1 \mod 3$ to $[20]_3^{-1}$ was the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means inverse of $20$ in the group of residue classes of module $3$. In other words you should find number $x$ that $x\times20\equiv1 \mod 3$.

Comment: I have gotten another example with the form $[24]_7^{-3}$?
Do you know what the $-3$ means?

Comment: It means the cube of inverse $([24]{_7}^{-1})^3$